# Call abort() on a Remote Object call

Tags: remote-objects

Currently I am calling the .retrieve() method on a keypress for a typeahead functionality.

I have faked the code so that when user pauses typing I then fire the call using setTimeout, but the issue is the fetch is 500ms extra, I am ok with that for now but for smooth streaming of data I want to call the AJAX on keypress and if user is still typing I want to abort that call.

A pseudo representation of what I am currently doing

```
onkeypress = {

   if(setTimeout is set){
       cancel existing timer;
   } 
   setimeout(Remoting(new Value keypress), 500)
}
```

What I want

```
onkeypress = {

   if(isRemoting call Dispatched){
       remotingCall.abort() // >> I need this
   } 
   Remoting call(new Value keypress)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no abort functionality that I know of but ...

a simple solution for this can be to only go for the retrieve after the first (or first two) characters are typed in and then filter on the returned list in JS.

You would have to consider that the limitation right now is 100 records per request so you'd have to use OFFSET and retrieve more data whenever the typed string does not have any matched in the already retrieved list.

Hope this makes sense!

If you are using VF RemoteObjects and AngularJS have a look at this little library [ngRemote](https://github.com/florianhoehn/ngRemote) which generates AngularJS services for each defined RemoteObject.

Hope this helps!

Florian

Comment: 100 records per request limit is for RemoteObjects and not for Visualforce remoting. Visualforce remoting has a limit for response size which is 15 MB. Also other apex limits apply.

Comment: But here we are talking about VF RemoteObjects, not JS Remoting...